# Creating empty rows on matrix of various size

Tags: r, matrix, rbind, cbind

I am trying to generate a matrix with the following data, Is there any way to  create empty rows to make matrix the same size?

```
#Generating original data
n <- c(12,24)
mu <- c(6.573,6.5)
sigma <- sqrt(0.25)
Diseased.Data <- round(rnorm(n[1],mu[1],sigma),4)
Healthy.Data <- round(rnorm(n[2],mu[2],sigma),4)
g <- c(2,3,4)

cstar.pool <- (mu[1]+mu[2])/2
#generating pooled data
for(i in 1:3){
  assign(paste("pool.dis.data",i,sep = ""),replicate(n[1]/g[i],mean(sample(Diseased.Data,g[i]))))
  assign(paste("pool.hel.data",i,sep = ""),replicate(n[2]/g[i],mean(sample(Healthy.Data,g[i]))))
}

#generating the pooled diseased data matrix
dis.mat1<- matrix(data = pool.dis.data1,length(pool.dis.data1),1)
dis.mat2 <- matrix(data = pool.dis.data2,length(pool.dis.data2),1)
dis.mat3 <- matrix(data = pool.dis.data3,length(pool.dis.data3),1)
dis.mat2 <- rbind(dis.mat2,NA)
dis.mat2 <- rbind(dis.mat2,NA)
dis.mat3 <- rbind(dis.mat3,NA)
dis.mat3 <- rbind(dis.mat3,NA)
dis.mat3 <- rbind(dis.mat3,NA)
dis.matrix <- matrix(NA, max(length(pool.dis.data1),length(pool.dis.data2),length(pool.dis.data3)),3)
dis.matrix[,1] <- cbind(dis.mat1)
dis.matrix[,2] <- cbind(dis.mat2)
dis.matrix[,3] <- cbind(dis.mat3)
```

Comment: not sure what you're asking, but if you want an empty 6X3 matrix, you can try: matrix(nrow = 6, ncol = 3) -> dis.matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say your best bet is to start out with an empty matrix of the size you need. You can tell matrix to specify the dimensions on creation like so:

```
new <- matrix( data = NA, nrow = 10, ncol = 20 )
```

So you just need to create a value for each dimension, based on your input data:

```
num.rows <- max( length(n), length(mu), ... )
num.columns <- [ I'd just enter a numeric value here ]
new <- matrix( data = NA, nrow = num.rows, ncol = num.columns )
```

Then you can fill the columns as needed, making sure to leave any excess empty. For example:

```
new[(1:length(n)),3] <- n
```

The "1:length(n)" part there will tell R to stop filling the column once the values you've given it have been entered. Otherwise R will continue filling, and you'll get repeated values, which I'm guessing you don't want.

Comment: Thank you, new[(1:length(n)),3] <- n, this was the command I was looking for. It helped a lot.